# Decode em full select

Tags: sql, oracle, vb.net, pl-sql

É possível eu realizar um decode em um select que retorna todos os dados de uma tabela e alguns de outras tabelas?

Neste select, gostaria de fazer um decode para uma das colunas de PP (pedido_peca), mas como ele faz uma busca full não sei se é possível e se possível, não sei como.

Por exemplo:
decode (cd_grupo, 1, Peca, 2, Acessório, null) 'Coluna da tabela pedido_peca no qual quero realizar o decode.

```
SELECT pp.*,
       g.nu_ordem_servico,
       g.dt_entrada,
       (g.dt_entrada + 30) as dt_vencimento,
       (select w.nm_perfil2
          from workflow w
         where w.id_processo = 7
           and w.cd_laudo = pp.id_status) as ds_status,
       conc.nu_cnpj || ' - ' || conc.sg_concessionario || ' - ' ||
       conc.nm_concessionario || ' - ' || conc.nm_cidade || ' - ' ||
       conc.sg_uf as sg_nm_concessionario,
       (select count(1)
          from ivv
         where dt_exclusao is null
           and nu_chassi = pp.ds_custom01
           and dt_limite_garantia > pp.dt_pedido) as ic_tem_garantia
  FROM pedido_peca pp
  left join garantia g
    on pp.nu_sg = g.nu_sg, concessionario conc
 WHERE pp.dt_exclusao is null
   and conc.dt_exclusao is null
   and g.dt_exclusao is null
   and pp.cd_concessionario = conc.id_concessionario
   and pp.id_pedido = 50360
   and pp.cd_concessionario = 5
```

Aqui está o código em VB.NET que irá retornar esse select acima.

```
        cfg.Abrir(DBProvider.enConnectionType.PEC)

        'Obtem Pedido
        sb = New System.Text.StringBuilder
        sb.Append(" SELECT ")
        sb.Append(" pp.*, ")
        sb.Append(" g.nu_ordem_servico, ")
        sb.Append(" g.dt_entrada, ")
        sb.Append(" (g.dt_entrada + 30) as dt_vencimento, ")
        sb.Append(" (select w.nm_perfil" & idPerfil & "  from workflow w where w.id_processo=7 and w.cd_laudo=pp.id_status) as ds_status, ")
        sb.Append(" conc.nu_cnpj ||' - '|| conc.sg_concessionario ||' - '|| conc.nm_concessionario ||' - '|| conc.nm_cidade ||' - '|| conc.sg_uf as sg_nm_concessionario, ")
        sb.Append(" (select count(1) from ivv where dt_exclusao is null and nu_chassi = pp.ds_custom01 and dt_limite_garantia > pp.dt_pedido) as ic_tem_garantia ")
        sb.Append(" FROM  pedido_peca pp left join garantia g on pp.nu_sg = g.nu_sg, concessionario conc ")
        sb.Append(" WHERE  ")
        sb.Append(" pp.dt_exclusao is null and ")
        sb.Append(" conc.dt_exclusao is null and ")
        sb.Append(" g.dt_exclusao is null and ")
        sb.Append(" pp.cd_concessionario = conc.id_concessionario and ")
        sb.Append(" pp.id_pedido = " & idPedido.ToString)

        If HttpContext.Current.Session("nivelusuario") > 10 Then

            sb.Append(" and pp.cd_concessionario = " & HttpContext.Current.Session("concessionario"))

        End If

        cfg.Fill(ds.Tables("Pedido"), sb.ToString)
```

Comment: As colunas são do mesmo tipo? Se sim, a sintaxe do decode é um IF THEN ELSE então deve ter no máximo 3 parametros e você passou 6. Pode explicar a condição real do decode informando inclusive campos e condição para avaliação?

Comment: A síntaxe do DECODE é limitada a do CASE mais flexível, pensou em usar CASE ?

Comment: @Caputo Quais colunas ? Pois no decode estou me referindo a apenas uma coluna, no qual é a pp.cd_grupo do tipo varchar2.
Minha intenção é fazer com que essa coluna caso o valor seja 1 traga o resultado Peça e caso valor 2  retorne Acessório.

Comment: @Motta Fiz uma tentativa com o CASE, mas encontrei o mesmo problema. Ao realizar o CASE no lugar de trazer o resultado esperado, é adicionado uma coluna a mais com o resultado do CASE, igual acontece quando faço o DECODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua sintaxe do DECODE está certa, faltaram as aspas nos textos. Montei um exemplo no sqlFiddle para validar

```
CREATE TABLE grupo (
    cdGrupo INTEGER,
    TextoGrupo VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO grupo (cdGrupo, TextoGrupo) VALUES (1, 'Teste');
INSERT INTO grupo (cdGrupo, TextoGrupo) VALUES (2, 'Teste 2');
INSERT INTO grupo (cdGrupo, TextoGrupo) VALUES (3, 'Teste 3');
INSERT INTO grupo (cdGrupo, TextoGrupo) VALUES (4, 'Teste 4');

SELECT 
  TextoGrupo,
  cdGrupo,
  DECODE(cdGrupo,
         1, 'Peça',
         2, 'Acessorio',
         3, 'Outra coisa',
         'Indefinido') As Tipo
FROM
  grupo;
```

### Resultado

```
TEXTOGRUPO |    CDGRUPO |   TIPO
-----------------------------------------
Teste      |    1       |   Peça
Teste 2    |    2       |   Acessorio
Teste 3    |    3       |   Outra coisa
Teste 4    |    4       |   Indefinido
```

### [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e3cda/3/0)

Comment: Funcionou, Obrigado !

Apaguei o comentário anterior pois postei sem querer.